# Monitor Async Task with Timeout and cancellation

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, .net-4.5

I All,

I have to monitor an async task, which has to be **cancellable** and do not perform more than specific **Time To Live**.

I already knew about the following code.

```
CancellationTokenSource l_cts = new CancellationTokenSource(timemillis);
```

which will doing the cancellation ( as far i monitor the token in my async method).
However, this NOT gave me any information about **WHY** he has been cancelled, **Timeout or user cancellation?** furthermore, the timeout event is delayed while i did not catch the cancellation with

```
Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

In order to solve these issues, I wrote the timeout process as follow.

```
    static async Task TestAsync(int processDelaySeconds, int cancelDelaySeconds, int timeoutDelaySeconds )
    {
        CancellationTokenSource l_cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        // the process to monitor
        Task l_process = new Task((state) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Process BEGIN");
            // dummy loop
            for (int l_i = 0; l_i != processDelaySeconds; l_i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                l_cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Process END");
        }, null, l_cts.Token);

        // register timeout
        RegisteredWaitHandle l_rwh = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(l_cts.Token.WaitHandle,
                (state, timedOut) =>
                {
                    if (timedOut)
                    {
                        l_cts.Cancel();
                        Console.WriteLine("Timed out");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Cancel Signaled");
                    }
                },
                null, (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutDelaySeconds).TotalMilliseconds, true);

        // cancel task
        if (cancelDelaySeconds > 0)
        {
            Task l_cancel = new Task(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(cancelDelaySeconds));
                l_cts.Cancel();
            });

            l_cancel.Start();
        }

        try
        {
            l_process.Start();
            await l_process;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task Cancelled");
        }
        finally
        {
            // be sure to unregister the wait handle to cancel the timeout
            if (l_process.Status != TaskStatus.Canceled) l_rwh.Unregister(l_cts.Token.WaitHandle);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Task Status is : {0}", l_process.Status);
    }  

    static async void Tests()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("NORMAL PROCESS");
        Console.WriteLine("--------------");
        await TestAsync(2, 10, 10);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("CANCEL");
        Console.WriteLine("------");
        await TestAsync(5, 2, 10);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("TIMEOUT");
        Console.WriteLine("-------");
        await TestAsync(10, 15, 2); 
    }
```

Then My question is :
Is there any drawbacks or traps behind the scene ?
A better and more efficient way ??

ps- Goal is performance, not shorter code.

Comment: You should use Task.Delay instead of Thread.Sleep if you want to delay execution. Especially if you are looking for performance.

Comment: Probably better fit for : [http://programmers.stackexchange.com/](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

If you need to distinguish between the user's and time-out cancellation, you can use `CreateLinkedTokenSource`:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        // worker
        private static void DoWork(CancellationToken token)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                Thread.Sleep(100); // do the work item
            }
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }

        // test
        private static void Main()
        {
            var userCt = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var combinedCt = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(
                userCt.Token);
            combinedCt.CancelAfter(3000); // cancel in 3 seconds

            Console.CancelKeyPress += (s, e) =>
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                userCt.Cancel();
            };

            var task = Task.Run(
                () => DoWork(combinedCt.Token), 
                combinedCt.Token);

            try
            {
                task.Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
                if (task.IsCanceled)
                {
                    if (userCt.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        Console.WriteLine("Cancelled by user");
                    else if (combinedCt.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        Console.WriteLine("Cancelled by time-out");
                    else 
                        Console.WriteLine("Cancelled by neither user nor time-out");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As to your original code, you really did not need `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(l_cts.Token.WaitHandle, ...)`, there's [`CancellationToken.Register`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321635%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that, which returns an `IDisposable` ready for use with `using`.

Comment: Thanks @Noseratio, One of the point is about WHEN the Timeout araised. If i'm blocked in a 'long' blocking task i want to know immediatly about the timeout instead has to waiting to detect the cancellation inside the job loop. I'm agree your solution is pretty and precise enought for 90% of use. Thank's again.

Comment: @GuillaumePelletier, if for some reason you can't use cooperative cancellation, you may want to use something like Stephen Toub's [`WithCancellation`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations.aspx) for your long-running tasks. You can combine it with `CreateLinkedTokenSource` if you need to distinguish between the user and time-out cancellation.

Answer (score 1):

In order to know if your Task has been cancelled or timed out, you can use the `Task.WaitAny` overload which takes a `TimeSpan`:

```
// Index will return -1 if timeout has occured, otherwise will print the index of the completed task
var cnclToken = new CancellationTokenSource().Token
var yourTask = Task.Run(() => { /* Do stuff */ }, cnclToken);
var index = Task.WhenAny(new[] { yourTask }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235645(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235645%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however, while we can do this using Task.WhenAny{mytask, Task.Delay(ms)} there is NO overload nor extension with time param on WhenAny. your related link is about WaitAny which return an int and NOT awaitable. The WhenAny method result on call to 2 Task which is waste of ressources (i believe, but maybe wrong). Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why is it a waste of resources? WaitAny will wait until either the Task or the TimeSpan will finish, there will only be one task, which is the one running your code.